# How can delete session from mongodb session through express

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose, passport.js, express-session

When I request to logout a user, it successfully logs out the user and redirects them to the sign in page, but the session record of that user is still available in the mongofb session table. And again, when I click on logout button. It destroys the session and logs out the user. I don't know how I can fix this issue. It looks like the user is not getting logged out.

app.js

```
mongoose.connect(
  'mongodb+srv://UserName:password@cluster0.orxsdfhy.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority',
   {useNewUrlParser:true, useUnifiedTopology:true  },

).then(()=>{})
 .catch(error => console.log(error))

 mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;

 app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
 app.use(cookieParser('secret'));

 app.use(session({
  secret: '7861',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: true,
  cookie: {
    secure: true,
    maxAge: 3000000 *60
  },
  store: MongoStore.create({
    mongooseConnection: mongoose.connection,
    mongoUrl:'mongodb+srv://UserName:password@cluster0.orxsdfhy.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority', 
    collection: 'session',
    ttl: 28800 
  }),
}));

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
app.use(flash());
require('./auth/passportAuthentication')(passport);
```

logOut.js

```
router.get("/logout", (req, res) => {

  req.logout(err => {
    if (err) {
      return next(err);
    } 
    req.session.destroy(function (err){
      if(err){
         console.log(err)
      } else {
         res.cookie("connect.sid",'')
         return res.sendStatus(200)
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: It could be that `req.logout()` and `req.session.destroy()` actually interfere with each other. For Passport it should be enough to run `req.logout()`; this won't remove the session, but it will remove any user-related data _from_ the session, effectively resetting it to a "logged out" state. If you really want to remove the session data from your database, don't use `req.logout()` but `req.session.destroy()`.

Comment: Now i am using only req.session.destroy(), but still session is stored in db